# How to run a trusted program as Admin on windows startup?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, administrator

I have a exe file that trusted by one of root certificate in my computer:

- The root certificate I create by openssl and installed in `Trusted Root` location in certificate store
- The exe file is singed by a client certificate trust by above cert and have `All application policies`, when view this exe file's properties, windows report that its cert is OK
- The exe is put in trusted location (C:\Program Files)
- I put file path in Startup Folder, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- My UAC setting is turn off
- Inside the exe file have this setting: `requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'`

Dispite what I had done, the program still refuse to start automaticly. Although I can add program in Schedule Task, or use other app to start this exe file successfully on startup,  I wonder if there is anyway to start it **directly**. Do you know any way to achieve it?

*PS: I'm running Windows 8.1 32 bit, use Administrator account and disable UAC setting.*

Comment: Do multiple users log on to this computer or is it just you?

Comment: @Steven just me. In fact I don't create any account at all, so I logged as Admin by default

Comment: You need to run the application as administrator, despite you already being administrator and UAC being off, thus you need to use task schedular which is the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: Well check this article, it will be needful for you ... http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Although I can add program in Schedule Task, or use other app to start this exe file successfully on startup, I wonder if there is anyway to start it directly.

Run it as a Scheduled Task "at log on" rather than "on startup."

Comment: Yes, I mean at log on, but I dont want rely on Schedule Task, if I can help it

Comment: Why don't you want to rely on a Scheduled Task?